# Error= tuple index out of range...problema con postgresql y python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, tkinter

tengo la siguiente función:

```
def Buscar(self):
    comando="SELECT * FROM tipo_inversion where id='"+self.palabra.get()+"';"
    conectar=Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos()
    conectar.cursor.execute(comando)
    #rows= conectar.cursor.fetchall()
    for dat in enumerate(conectar.cursor.fetchall()):
        self.listbox.insert(0, Label(self.listbox, text=dat[0]))
        self.listbox.insert(1, Label(self.listbox, text=dat[1]))
        self.listbox.insert(2, Label(self.listbox, text=dat[2]))
        self.listbox.insert(3, Label(self.listbox, text=dat[3]))
```

Estoy usando un ciclo para acomodar 4 datos que tengo en una tabla en postgresql, pero la verdad no se si estoy bien así, me sale este error:

```
self.listbox.insert(1, Label(self.listbox, text=dat[2]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

antes tenía solo la listbox y con fetchall, llamaba a `self.listbox.insert(0, *rows)` lo de rows esta comentado en la primera función

pero no me gusta como muestra los datos, ya que se ven muy pegados y quiero que tengan un poco de espacio, por eso intente con el ciclo y creando un label. para esto, me base en este codigo:

```
Label(self.ventanaBusqueda, text=dat[0]).grid(row=index+1, column=0)
        Label(self.ventanaBusqueda, text=dat[1]).grid(row=index+1, column=1)
        Label(self.ventanaBusqueda, text=dat[2]).grid(row=index+1, column=2)
        Label(self.ventanaBusqueda, text=dat[3]).grid(row=index+1, column=3)
```

y poniendolo de esta manera, no puedo acomodarlo donde tengo la listbox, es decir la posicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `dat[2]` no existe, `dat` es una tupla de dos elementos por lo que el índice 2 no existe.

La función *built-in* `enumerate(sequence, start=0)` recibe como argumentos cualquier iterable (`secuence`) y un entero (`start`), que es 0 por defecto. Retorna un iterador que va generando tuplas de dos elementos que contienen un contador (que empieza en `start`) y los valores obtenidos al iterar sobre la secuencia.

Mejor verlo con algunos ejemplos:

```
>>> secuencia = ["Hola", "StackOverflow", "en", "español"]

>>> for e in enumerate(secuencia):
        print(e)

(0, 'Hola')
(1, 'StackOverflow')
(2, 'en')
(3, 'español')

>>> for e in enumerate(secuencia, 10):
        print(e)

(10, 'Hola')
(11, 'StackOverflow')
(12, 'en')
(13, 'español')


>>> for indice, palabra in enumerate(secuencia):
        print("Indice: {}  Palabra: {}".format(indice, palabra))

Indice: 0  Palabra: Hola
Indice: 1  Palabra: StackOverflow
Indice: 2  Palabra: en
Indice: 3  Palabra: español
```

Esta es la causa del error que tienes, para dar una solución más específica seria necesario saber como quieres que se vean los datos exactamente y la estructura de tu tabla.

Comment: utilice el .format como tu en el ultimo ejemplo y me funciono muy bien. ahora me muestra cada dato en fila, gracias `self.listbox.insert(0, "Id: {}".format(dato2[0]))
            self.listbox.insert(1, "Nombre: {}".format(dato2[1]))
            self.listbox.insert(2, "porcentaje de utilidad: {}".format(dato2[2]))
            self.listbox.insert(3, "tasa de pago: {}".format(dato2[3]))`